# Loading bar in react redux not working 100%

Tags: reactjs, redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75hs8.jpg)I have a problem with using React Redux Loading Bar. It working 98.89% and stopping here. I dont get any error. But it not working 100% and stop. what mistake am I making here? Thank you so much and sorry for my weak English skill

here is my Reducer.js

```
import { loadingBarReducer } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'
export default combineReducers({
  ....
  loadingBar: loadingBarReducer
})
```

here is my Store

```
...
import { loadingBarMiddleware } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'
const epic = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)
const composeEnhancers = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export function configureStore(initializeState: any = {}) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initializeState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(loadingBarMiddleware(), thunk, epic))
  )
}
```

here is my component

```
import LoadingBar from 'react-redux-loading-bar'
...

  <div>
     <LoadingBar />
  </div>
```

Comment: That is not enough information.

Comment: i use library react-redux-loadingbar follow the instruction https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar

Comment: @paruchuri-p, don't just say "not enough information". What else do you need to know in order to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

This library does not automate things for redux-thunk as it does for redux-promise and redux-saga. To use thunk with it you would have to call:

```
dispatch(showLoading())
// do long running stuff
dispatch(hideLoading())
```

in your action creators. That is how I got it to work.

https://github.com/mironov/react-redux-loading-bar/issues/34